# Does OCI DNS support domain name registration?

Tags: oracle, dns, registration

I was trying to find a proper DNS solution.

I found that Azure don't support domain name registration right now, and they are clearly stating it in their official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-faq#does-azure-dns-support-domain-name-registration

But what about OCI? I can only find these details from the official documentation:
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/DNS/Concepts/gettingstarted.htm

> Public DNS Zones hold the trusted DNS records that will reside on
> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure's nameservers. You can create public zones
> with publicly available domain names.

> To make your Oracle Cloud Infrastructure hosted zone accessible
> through the internet, you must delegate your domain with your domain's
> registrar.

> You can use the noted name servers to change your domain's DNS
> delegation. Refer to your registrar's documentation for instructions.

This is from FAQ: https://www.oracle.com/in/cloud/networking/dns-faq.html

> **How do I delegate my domain to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure DNS?**
>
> Domains can be delegated to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure DNS from the
> Domain Registrar’s self-service portal.

Can i buy a public domain via OCI DNS?

Or should i use a third party registrar to buy a domain first, and then create a zone for that domain in OCI DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle cloud does not act as a domain registrar, so you cannot buy a domain from them. You can have DNS servers both primary and secondaries, on Oracle cloud
for domains registered elsewhere.